# How do I configure my service to get session from a single database?

Tags: java, database, oracle, jdbc, database-connection

I have 3 databases(Test1, Test2, Test3) in Oracle. I need to run a query from a table that exists only in Test1 and not in the other databases. How do I configure my service get a session from that particular database using hibernate sessionFactory.

If you need more info, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: I believe that is what you are looking for
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921865/how-to-connect-to-multiple-databases-in-hibernate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921865/how-to-connect-to-multiple-databases-in-hibernate)

Comment: That's exactly what I am looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate session factory takes a JDBC URL. The JDBC URL for Oracle contain the database name:

```
  jdbc:oracle:<drivertype>:@<database>
```

For example:

```
dbc:oracle:thin:@myhost:1521:orcl
```

So you specify which database you connect to via the URL.