# Can I integrate a MySQL and a PostgreSQL database into a Spring MVC Maven Project?

Tags: mysql, database, spring, postgresql, maven

I'm working on a project and I have been using MySQL as the primary database for a number of entities with their respective relations in place. The purpose of the project is to rate neighbourhoods in my hometown based on a number of criteria, one of which is house prices. I have an excel sheet with 36,000 + records of house sales, their prices and the lat and long of the house. A user will search a  location, and a latitude and longitude will be calculated. I aim to return all the lat, long and house price values from the records of house sales within a radius of 1km so I can calculate the average house price for that respective area. Please see the screenshot below for a visual aid of what I'm talking about.

[image: Screenshot of Application]

Based on research it seems that maybe the PostGIS extension for Postgresql is the way to go as it has a lot of tools for querying data based on geographic criteria.

As I have a MySQL DB already in place and I have no intention of creating a relationship between the entities in that DB and the house prices in a potential Postgresql DB can I and/or is it possible to have 2 separate databases in one MVC spring project or should I include everything in just one DB?

Comment: You can use two database engines, I recomended you to add some ORM like hibernate to handle both connections and sessions.

Comment: @mvlaicevich thanks for the reply! Would you be familiar with a resource I could look at that might help to get me started on that. I have hibernate added already just unfamiliar with how I would get two database engines integrated into the project.

Comment: look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921865/how-to-connect-to-multiple-databases-in-hibernate

Comment: @mvlaicevich can I have both MySQL and PostgreSQL listening on the same 8080 port?

Comment: Each connection has its own port for db connection, 8080 is for application, and yes, you can have both connections on same application running