# Multi tenancy in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

I am having issues creating a spring boot application that can dynamically connect to multiple databases, depending on user input. Basically the application runs the same sql query on different databases. modeling my attempt after [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28821521/configure-datasource-programmatically-in-spring-boot), i have received the following error:

```
2018-04-10 16:18:50.678 ERROR 15716 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : HikariPool-1 - dataSource or dataSourceClassName or jdbcUrl is required.
```

--

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: dataSource or  dataSourceClassName or jdbcUrl is required.
```

config class:

```
@Configuration
public class ReconDBConfig {


@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.foo")
@Bean
@Primary
public DataSource fooDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder
            .create()
            .build();
}

@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.bar")
@Bean
public DataSource barDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder
            .create()
            .build();
}
}
```

Properties file:

```
spring.datasource.foo.url        =     jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/fooDB
spring.datasource.foo.user       =  admin
spring.datasource.foo.password   =  admin
spring.datasource.foo.driver     =  org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.foo.maxconn    =  5
spring.datasource.foo.expiry     =  180
spring.datasource.foo.cache      =  true
spring.datasource.foo.retry      =  3
spring.datasource.foo.retrydelay =  30

spring.datasource.bar.url        =     jdbc:postgresql://not_localhost:5432/fooDB
spring.datasource.bar.user       =  definitely_not_admin
spring.datasource.bar.password   =  definitely_not_admin
spring.datasource.bar.driver     =  org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.bar.maxconn    =  5
spring.datasource.bar.expiry     =  180
spring.datasource.bar.cache      =  true
spring.datasource.bar.retry      =  3
spring.datasource.bar.retrydelay =  30
```

any ideas on how i can accomplish this? i am, as you can tell, not super savvy with this multiple db configuration yet.

Comment: Does that error show up at every attempt or just after the first connection is succesful?

Comment: every time, well ive only tried building the project less than 10 times... but each one of those times..

Comment: Comment out one of the beans and  see if you get the same error. Having two, the exception is not telling you which one is causing the problem

Comment: that has been done, same error. i am sure it has something to do with the ' dataSource or dataSourceClassName or jdbcUrl is required' but im not sure how to add that in

Comment: Have you tried configuring it as pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921865/how-to-connect-to-multiple-databases-in-hibernate)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataSourceBuilder.create().build()` is going to instantiate `HikariDataSource` as it is the default DataSource as of SpringBoot 2.0. If you look into **HikariDataSource** source code the properties are **jdbcUrl**, **username** NOT **url**, **user**. So, you need to change property keys in **application.properties** file as follows:

```
spring.datasource.foo.jdbcUrl=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/fooDB
spring.datasource.foo.username=admin
...
...
spring.datasource.bar.jdbcUrl=jdbc:postgresql://not_localhost:5432/fooDB
spring.datasource.bar.username=definitely_not_admin
...
...
```

In order to use different dataSource based on some request parameters, you might have to use Spring's **AbstractRoutingDataSource** as explained here https://spring.io/blog/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/.